# How can I test my locally stored webpages?

Tags: html, browser, web, device

I have my HTML pages locally stored on my Mac. I already bought the domain and the hosting service. There's a way with which I can test these local webpages so that I can see how they render on different devices? I have heard about local server for testing or using devices via USB attached to the PC. Is there not a more standard and unified way to testing them? It can be everything (software, online services, ...) I'm not interested in emulators/simulators.

Comment: There are sooo many variables involved that makes your question far too abroad for an objective answer. It is possible to run php, mysql, asp, sql server, and uncontable kinds of features you can have online. So, if you don't specify what site you're building, expect no useful answers. Try asking in parts, step by step. Best.

Comment: @statosdotcom I'm building a personal website. I write my own HTML5 pages locally stored in my Mac. To make an example, I heard about the WebInspector offered by Safari + iOS, but this isn't able to "transfer" the display of a webpages from the PC to the smartphone, but only to make debug of the page itself.

Comment: Things begin to clear, now we know you have html5 pages, nice. To have a first glimpse of your pages on your smartphone, you could simply copy files and folders to the phone and open it with your browser. But this way you will only get your pages running in a single phone, one or two browsers. You will have to search more about testing this on many devices. At the same time you can rely on www standards and specifications (search w3.org - there are html and css validators there) to ensure you're implementing good practices. Nobody see own pages in all devices, how they do? You do the same.

Comment: I already use validators, both for HTML and CSS, and I try to follow all W3C standards. Have you ever heard about local server?

Comment: Well install Apache, or some wamp for macs... Have you ever heard about Wamp? Xamp? There are plenty of local servers for smartphones too.

Comment: Yes I do, but never tried to use them

Comment: Concerning your own "static" files and folders ("static pages"? You know?, ok), if this is the case, it really doesn't matter if your browser are opening by "file open" or through http protocol, if references to external resources are ok. The resulting page, displayed on your browser will be exactelly the same. This way you don't need a local server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Creating a local server: Node.js and BrowserSync

I've found a very simple way to test webpages (in my case, HTML5 pages) that are saved in PCs memory so that we could test them directly into all the different devices available, without using simulators/emulators. 
The solution is creating a **local server** using two great totally free tools: **Node.js** and **BrowserSync**. Before writing this answer, I tried this solution on my own, and I was completely satisfied of the result! You can find the source for this answer at [JavaScript Kit](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/mobilefriendly2.shtml).

Here you are the main steps:

1. Install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) (verify if Node.js is correctly installed with the `node- v` command from the terminal);
2. Install [BrowserSync](https://www.browsersync.io/) using `npm install -g browser-sync` directly from the terminal. Be careful you need **root permissions** (I simply used `sudo npm install -g browser-sync`);
3. Run BrowserSync:

   - Navigate to your target directory (the one which contain the **static** files used to create the website, that's the HTML (and CSS) files) using the command line (to make an example, it could be `cd folderA/folderB`);
   - Create a local server inside that directory, with `browser-sync start --server`.

These are the main steps, but you can directly read the solution from the original source I linked some lines before.

Answer (score 0):

**If you have only html and/or Javascript code:**

- Open it with your browser, it will be enough

**If you have PHP code:**

- Install a local web-server (Ex: Apache)

**If you have MySQL code:**

- Install a MySQL server

Usually, installing Mamp (or an equivalent for Android/iOS) is enough to do every basic things. It will provide you SQL and PHP server
Hope it helped you